# Trigger jQuery event when input field is filled externally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `date type` field in my html form and I am submitting the form through ajax. In this `date type` field i have a calendar icon which opens the calendar when click on it.

Now problem I have is when the field is filled with the user selected `date`. I am not able to fire any event because it filled the value without any `focusin` and other jQuery events are failed to capture. How to capture the event whenever the field is filled in.

This is my html I am using

```
<input type="text" name="" class="date_field_input" id="expiration_date_c" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" title="">
    <button type="button" id="expiration_date_c_trigger" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return false;"><span class="suitepicon suitepicon-module-calendar" alt="Enter Date"></span></button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup ({
                                inputField : "expiration_date_c",
                                form : "EditView",
                                ifFormat : "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",
                                daFormat : "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",
                                button : "expiration_date_c_trigger",
                                singleClick : true,
                                dateStr : "",
                                startWeekday: 0,
                                step : 1,
                                weekNumbers:false
                                }
                            );
    </script>
```

Comment: does ".on('change',... " not work?

Comment: @Bobert1234 no it is not working as it is not changing any behavior of input field.

Comment: @fatpotato you can use `on('input', ...)`

Comment: @NeelBhanushali still not any luck

Comment: @fatpotato if you can make a working snippet, so as to get a better understanding about the problem

Comment: let me make an jsfiffle if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

would the trigger method on the input field work for you?

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: we for the trigger we still needs to have an event like click, input but how will it trigger automatically whenever there is value in that fields.